# Aurelia .withMessage validation css

Tags: css, aurelia

I have the following code:

JS

```
                    .if(() => { return this.HasProvidedEitherSku1OrSku2 === false })
                        .isNotEmpty().withMessage(‘at least one sku is required')
                        .hasLengthBetween(0, 50)
                    .endIf()                    
                    .ensure('Sku2', (config) => {config.computedFrom(['Sku1'])})
                    .if(() => { return this.HasProvidedEitherSku1OrSku2 === false })
                        .isNotEmpty().withMessage(‘at least one sku is required’)
                        .hasLengthBetween(0, 50)
                    .endIf();
```

HTML

```
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">SKU</label>
                <input disabled.bind="readonly" type="text" class="form-control" value.bind="Sku1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label"> SKU</label>
                <input disabled.bind="readonly" type="text" class="form-control" value.bind="Sku2">
            </div>
        </div>
```

withMessage seens to react differently when contained within an if statement. rather than adding a '`has-warning`' to the `form-group`. It just adds:

```
<p class="help-block **aurelia-validation-message**">at least one sku is required</p>
```

How do I force a 'has-warning'? Or have something close to an if statement. If p class = "" then grab label above and input below.